# java program to return the characters which occurs more than 3 times in a string using only string functions

Tags: string, function, character

java program to return the characters which occurs more than 3 times in a string using only string functions
use only charAt and length functions to get solution

```
import java.util.*;
public class StringExample {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
       String str = "sofiiiffjjjh";
       Map < Character, Integer > charFreq = new HashMap < Character, Integer > ();
       if (str != null) {
           for (Character c: str.toCharArray()) {
               Integer count = charFreq.get(c);
               int newCount = (count == null ? 1 : count + 1);
               charFreq.put(c, newCount);
               if (newCount >= 3) {
                   System.out.println(c);
                }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried with collections

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: But i dont know how to do it using only loops and string

Comment: import java.util.*;
public class StringExample
{ 
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  String str="sofiiiffjjjh";
  Map<Character,Integer> charFreq = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
    if (str != null) 
    {
      for (Character c : str.toCharArray()) 
      {
       Integer count = charFreq.get(c);
       int newCount = (count==null ? 1 : count+1);
        charFreq.put(c, newCount);
         if(newCount>=3)
         {
          System.out.println(c);
         }
      }
      
    }
    
  } 
 }

Comment: private static Scanner s;
        public static void main(String [] args) {
            String n, a[];
            int i,j,l;
            System.out.println("Enter the string: ");
            s= new Scanner(System.in);
            n=s.nextLine();
            a=n.split("");
            l = a.length;
            for(i=0; i<l; i++){
                for(j=i+1; j<l; j++){
                    if(a[i].equals(a[j])) {
                        System.out.println(a[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
      }

Comment: i even tried this. but how to get characters which repeats only 3 or more than 3 times@user75

Comment: Please add any code to the post as it is not easy to read from comments

Comment: it is not letting me to edit the post. showing error

Comment: can u pls help me with this. @user7

Answer (score 0):

This solution first sorts the character in the input string. It loops through the characters in the string, comparing the current character with the previous character
1. If they are the same, it increments the count
2. If not, it checks the number of times `previousChar` has occurred and prints it if it is more than 3 and continues.

```
char [] strAsArray = s.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(strAsArray);
String sorted = new String(strAsArray);
System.out.println(sorted);

if (sorted.length() > 0) {
    char previousChar = s.charAt(0);
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < sorted.length(); i++) {
        if (sorted.charAt(i) == previousChar) {
            count++;
        } else {   // encountered new character
            if (count >= 3) {
                //if the previous character has appeared more than 3 times
                System.out.println(sorted.charAt(i - 1));
            }
            count = 1;
            previousChar = sorted.charAt(i);
        }
    }

    //To handle case where the String has only one character any number of times
    if (count >= 3) {
        System.out.println(sorted.charAt(sorted.length() - 1));
    }
}
```